# How to import external module in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

My code below is working fine:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import user from './modules/auth';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        user
    }
 });
```

Is there a shorter way to import a module instead of writing the statement at the top? I instead write it directly inside the modules like below:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        user: import('./modules/auth'),
    }
 });
```

But unfortunately it didn't work (the external module was not imported successfully).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to shorten the code for importing modules here.

Comment: There is just no need to shorten this. If you're using Webpack you MIGHT be able to do: user: () => import('./modules/auth') - let me know if this works for you

Comment: @Trent I already that Sir but the same from my above code, it just shows empty object when I log it. I just ask because I thought it will become so lengthy in the future if I had lots of module.

Comment: That's the way it should be declared, there's no need to refactor the code. Your code is good. Just organize the modules directory as what you're doing.

Comment: @JuanCervantes - I think you miss read my comment. What I wrote is not the same as what you have. Notice the anonymous function? user: () => import()... is not the same as user: import()...

Answer (score 2):

`Import` with braces is different from `import` without braces - the latter imports the module statically (at compile time) while the former imports the module dynamically (at run time) and is not an ES6 feature but something specific to Webpack.

You can read more in the [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-1) but the most important thing is that dynamic imports (those with braces) return a `Promise` instead of module reference. The module reference will be available when the Promise resolves. You can read more about lazy-loading Vuex modules in this article https://itnext.io/vue-js-app-performance-optimization-part-3-lazy-loading-vuex-modules-ed67cf555976

Answer (score 0):

Before beginning, I'm using Vue 3 + Vuex 4.

In the file path/to/store/index.js that hold the Vuex store I used the code like this.

```
// path/to/store/index.js
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import moduleA from './modules/moduleA';
import moduleB from './modules/moduleB';

export default createStore({
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  getters: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {
    moduleA,
    moduleB,
  },
});
```

And I created a file for each module as this

```
// file for each module
export default {
  state: { ... },
  mutations: { ... },
  getters: { ... },
  actions: { ... },
  modules: { ... },
};
```